Is there any way to improve or adjust familiar stats in PF1e?
Basically what it says on the tin; I'm playing in a campaign where I've taken the leadership feat, and I have 1st level wizards to manage. I'm looking for something low level that can improve or otherwise adjust a familiar's stats without taking improved familiar. Even a +1 or moving one stat to another would be awesome.
Its a long shot, and I understand why messing with familiar ability stats is difficult, but I was wondering if I had any options?
